# Mql4 How to set toggle button ON OFF state?

Tags: mql4

I'm making a line of on-chart buttons that will launch specific functions and indicators. So far so good the buttons load an indicator when pressed and delete it when the button is unpressed.

But I would like to add two more functions to the button but I'm doing something wrong and it doesn't work properly and I need some help.

1st - I would like the button do be able to detect indicator on chart an automatically set the button to "ON" state in case I will drag and drop the indicator from indicator list.

2nd - when I press the button it will launch an indicator popup window and we have 2 options;

1 - "OK" which will launch the indicator on the chart and the button will stay in "ON" state.

2 - "CANCEL" which will abort lunching the indicator but it will leave the button in "ON" state. I would like the button to go back to the "OFF" state just after I press "CANCEL".

Here is a peace of the code for testing.

```
#property indicator_chart_window
string sButtonName1 ="B1";
string sButtonName2 ="B2";
const string IndiName1  ="X";
const string IndiName2  ="Y";

//--------------------------------------------------------------

color UnloadedColor=clrGray;
color LoadedColor=clrBlue;
color currentColor;

//--------------------------------------------------------------

#import "user32.dll"
void keybd_event(int bVk,int bScan,int dwFlags,int dwExtraInfo);
#define  VK_L 0x4C
#define  VK_M 0x4D
#define  VK_MENU 0x12
#define  KEYEVENTF_KEYUP 0x0002
#import

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
  {
   int buttonwindow=ObjectFind(sButtonName1);
   int buttonwindow1=ObjectFind(sButtonName2);
 {
  if(buttonwindow<0)
     CreateButton1(sButtonName1,UnloadedColor,"Arial",0);
  if(buttonwindow1<0)
     CreateButton2(sButtonName2,UnloadedColor,"Arial",0);
 }
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
//+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|------------------------CreateButton 1--------------------------------------------|
//+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CreateButton1(string sName1,color sColor,string sFont="Arial",string sText="")
  {
   ObjectCreate(0,sName1,OBJ_BUTTON,0,0,0);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName1,OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,725);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName1,OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,0);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName1,OBJPROP_XSIZE,50);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName1,OBJPROP_YSIZE,50);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName1,OBJPROP_CORNER,4);
   ObjectSetString(0,sName1,OBJPROP_TEXT,"X");
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName1,OBJPROP_COLOR,sColor);
   ObjectSetString(0,sName1,OBJPROP_FONT,sFont);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName1,OBJPROP_FONTSIZE,26);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName1,OBJPROP_STATE,false);
  }
//+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|------------------------CreateButton 2--------------------------------------------|
//+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CreateButton2(string sName2,color sColor,string sFont="Arial",string sText="")
  {
   ObjectCreate(0,sName2,OBJ_BUTTON,0,0,0);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName2,OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,775);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName2,OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,0);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName2,OBJPROP_XSIZE,50);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName2,OBJPROP_YSIZE,50);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName2,OBJPROP_CORNER,4);
   ObjectSetString(0,sName2,OBJPROP_TEXT,"Y");
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName2,OBJPROP_COLOR,sColor);
   ObjectSetString(0,sName2,OBJPROP_FONT,sFont);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName2,OBJPROP_FONTSIZE,26);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,sName2,OBJPROP_STATE,false);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnChartEvent(const int id,
              const long &lparam,
              const double &dparam,
              const string &sparam) 
 {
//+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+--------------------------------------- BUTTON 1 ---------------------------------+
//+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 {
    {
     if(id==CHARTEVENT_OBJECT_CLICK && sparam==sButtonName1)
       {
        currentColor=ObjectGetInteger(0,sButtonName1,OBJPROP_COLOR);
        if(currentColor==UnloadedColor)
          {
           keybd_event(VK_MENU,0,0,0);
           keybd_event(VK_L,0,0,0);
           keybd_event(VK_L,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
           keybd_event(VK_MENU,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);

           ObjectSetInteger(0,sButtonName1,OBJPROP_COLOR,LoadedColor);
           return;
          }
        else
           if(currentColor==LoadedColor)
             {
              ChartIndicatorDelete(0,0,IndiName1);
              ObjectSetInteger(0,sButtonName1,OBJPROP_COLOR,UnloadedColor);
             }
       }
    }

  //+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  //+---------------------------------------BUTTON 2-----------------------------------+
  //+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

    {
     if(id==CHARTEVENT_OBJECT_CLICK && sparam==sButtonName2)
       {
        currentColor=ObjectGetInteger(0,sButtonName2,OBJPROP_COLOR);
        if(currentColor==UnloadedColor)
          {
           keybd_event(VK_MENU,0,0,0);
           keybd_event(VK_M,0,0,0);
           keybd_event(VK_M,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
           keybd_event(VK_MENU,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);

           ObjectSetInteger(0,sButtonName2,OBJPROP_COLOR,LoadedColor);
           return;
          }
        else
           if(currentColor==LoadedColor)
             {
              ChartIndicatorDelete(0,0,IndiName2);
              ObjectSetInteger(0,sButtonName2,OBJPROP_COLOR,UnloadedColor);
             }
       }
    }
 }

/*

//+-------------------------------------NOT WORKING-----------------------------------+

//------------------------------ DETECT INDICATOR ON THE CHART-------------------------------

 {
  int indicators_total = ChartIndicatorsTotal(0,0);
  for(int i = 0; indicators_total > i; i++)

//+------------------------- INDICATOR 1 DETECTED -----------------------------------

    {
     if(ChartIndicatorName(0,0,i)==IndiName1)
       {
        currentColor=ObjectGetInteger(0,sButtonName1,OBJPROP_COLOR);
        if(currentColor==UnloadedColor)
          {
           ObjectSetInteger(0,sButtonName1,OBJPROP_STATE,true);
           ObjectSetInteger(0,sButtonName1,OBJPROP_COLOR,LoadedColor);
          }
       }
//+------------------------- INDICATOR 1 NOT DETECTED -----------------------------------

     if(!(ChartIndicatorName(0,0,i)==IndiName1))
       {
        currentColor=ObjectGetInteger(0,sButtonName1,OBJPROP_COLOR);
        if(currentColor==LoadedColor)
          {
           ObjectSetInteger(0,sButtonName1,OBJPROP_STATE,false);
           ObjectSetInteger(0,sButtonName1,OBJPROP_COLOR,UnloadedColor);
          }
       }
//+------------------------- INDICATOR 2 DETECTED-----------------------------------
     if(ChartIndicatorName(0,0,i)==IndiName2)
       {
        currentColor=ObjectGetInteger(0,sButtonName2,OBJPROP_COLOR);
        if(currentColor==UnloadedColor)
          {
           ObjectSetInteger(0,sButtonName2,OBJPROP_STATE,true);
           ObjectSetInteger(0,sButtonName2,OBJPROP_COLOR,LoadedColor);
          }
       }
//+------------------------- INDICATOR 2 NOT DETECTED -----------------------------------

     if(!(ChartIndicatorName(0,0,i)==IndiName2))
       {
        currentColor=ObjectGetInteger(0,sButtonName2,OBJPROP_COLOR);
        if(currentColor==LoadedColor)
          {
           ObjectSetInteger(0,sButtonName2,OBJPROP_STATE,false);
           ObjectSetInteger(0,sButtonName2,OBJPROP_COLOR,UnloadedColor);
          }
       }
    }
 }
//+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

*/
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
            const int prev_calculated,
            const datetime &time[],
            const double &open[],
            const double &high[],
            const double &low[],
            const double &close[],
            const long &tick_volume[],
            const long &volume[],
            const int &spread[])
  {
   return(rates_total);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: you need to check `ObjectGetInteger(0,sName2,OBJPROP_STATE)` and same for the first object. if it is true, button is pressed, if false - it is not pressed

Comment: Hi, I've already tried it, it's the same as my 

`ObjectGetInteger(0,sButtonName1,OBJPROP_COLOR);`

the thing is the button misbehave when  

`int indicators_total = ChartIndicatorsTotal(0,0);`
`for(int i = 0; indicators_total > i; i++)`

is used in `OnChartEvent `

I've tried it in `OnCalculate `, but only detecting indicator on the chart was working. 
When I've added lines to detect the absence of the indicator on the chart the button state start to misbehave and `OnChartEvent ` wasn't working properly.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783672/how-to-use-indicator-count-and-how-to-turn-key-event-into-code-in-mql4 before going forward. If your problem is to determine whether there's the same indicator on the chart, the answer is there. You have to link that solution to `ObjectGetInteger(0,***,OBJPROP_STATE) and that's it !